# Azure container registry using Azure Private Link - can't access the "Repositories" area

Tags: azure, security, azure-container-registry

I've set up an Azure container registry using an Azure Private Link only - so it's not available on internet. All seems to work but when I enter the "Repositories" area then instaed of the list of repositories, I can see only error message saying:

ERROR: **"Looks like you don't have access to this content. Are firewalls and virtual networks enabled?"**

[image]

When I go to the "Networking" area, I can see that "Allow trusted Microsoft services to access this container registry" is checked and public network access is set to "Disabled":

[image]

I created the registry inside a new resource group and a new virtual network. The resource group only contains a virutal network and the registry. The Repositories area starts working when I enable public access to the registry and it stops when I disable it.

Comment: `Allow trusted Microsoft services to access this container registry` is kind of a scam. Do read the documentation 0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/allow-access-trusted-services

Answer (score 5):

Read the error message again -

> Looks like you don't have access to this content. Are firewalls and
> virtual networks enabled?

The firewall blocks access from internet and in your case your access too. Sounds weird; but the thing is Azure understands that the portal view is from your public IP which is un-allowed and that's why you don't see any content there.

*What to do in this case*-

Choose the option selected network and add your IP in the list there-
[image]

You will be able to see the CR there now.
Since your private link is already working, you are good with that already.